# Network API to return HTTPS response in iPhone

Tags: swift, https, nsurlrequest, xcode-6.2

**Can I return the server response from any function to its calling function using any of the Network API like AFNetworking, MKNetworkKit etc, in iPhone.**

Currently I am using httpGet function of NSURLRequest. I made the following function but I am not able to return the server response to it calling function. Please help me.

```
func connserv(jsonString:NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary{
    var abc: NSDictionary?
    // This is the action performed when clicked on the Connect button on the connectivity screen
    println("------------------Function connserv")

    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var IP: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("IP")!
    var port: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("Port")!
    println("IP in Connection : \(IP)")
    println("port in Connection : \(port)")
    prefs.synchronize()
    //var learn = LearnNSURLSession()
    let localizedModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().localizedModel
    let model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
    let devicesystemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion

    println("HTTP request jsonString : \(jsonString)")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://\(IP):\(port)/")!)

    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?

    //println("HTTP request jsonString : \(jsonString)")

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    // send the request
    var learn = LearnNSURLSession()
    println("HTTP request : \(request)")
    learn.httpGet(request) {
        (resultString, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            println("completion block")

        }
        else
        {
            let data = (resultString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var er: NSError?
            let JSONdata: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers,error: &er)!

            let abc: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&er)!

            println("abc : \(abc)")
            println("JSONdata : \(JSONdata)")

            learn.callback(result: resultString, error: error)
        }
    }
    //return abc!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your `LearnNSURLSession` class works, so I cannot suggest a solution with that. But here is how to find the returned headers and status, together with the returned data and any error information, from an NSURLConnection, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:):

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), completionHandler: {
        response, data, error in
        if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            debugPrintln(response.allHeaderFields)
            let statusCode = response.statusCode
            debugPrintln("statusCode: \(statusCode): \(NSHTTPURLResponse.localizedStringForStatusCode(statusCode))")
        } else { println("That's odd.") }
    })
```

While that documentation suggests that the response is an `NSURLResponse`, [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSHTTPURLResponse) makes clear that you will get a `NSHTTPURLResponse` which contains all the headers and status.

If you need a synchronous version, that will stop the function until it gets a result, you can use [this call instead](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:), like this:

```
var response:NSURLResponse?
var e: NSError?
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &e)
debugPrintln(response)
```

That will allow you to return a meaningful result to the caller.

Comment: Emrys57, I get the response and everything from server. There is no problem in it. I want to return the server response to the calling function of the connserv function. And the issue is there. I hope u have a better idea now

Comment: I will try it. Can I not do the samething in asynchronous connection?

Comment: The whole point of an async connection is that the function that sets up the connection returns before the connection is complete. So it cannot return the result of the connection to the calling code, by design.

Comment: Emrys57, can you please tell me how can I establish a synchronous connection and send a JSON request in it.

Comment: You can just use the code I put in my answer, 'sendSynchronousRequest', with the request you have already created in your question. Look in the response with debugPrintln to work out what data you want to return to the caller.

Comment: Emrys57, I used your code but this function did not send anything to server.

Comment: Emrys57, And I want to return the server response to the caller function

Comment: Emrys57, I am doing coding in swift

Comment: When I used your code I got the following error:                                                          HTTP request : <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7b196010> { URL: https://144.1.1.45:9299/ }

2015-04-06 19:34:29.320 App[872:20815] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

nil

response-------------------------> : nil

2015-04-06 19:34:29.322 App[872:20534] Unknown class UIAlert in Interface Builder file.

Comment: Looks like your server did not respond. If you want to know why your new code is not working, you should ask another question, and post your new code. Good Luck!

Comment: Emrys57, I have asked a question and added the new code as per your suggestion. Link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484914/establish-synchronous-connection-with-the-sever-in-swift

Comment: Emrys57, I have re-run the code and found that server does not receive any thing.

Comment: Emrys57, please help me with this