# Establish synchronous connection with the sever in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, nsurlconnection, server

I have the following function to establish the connection synchronously with the sever on a particular IP and port, send a JSON request to sever and return the server's response to the calling function.

```
func connserv(jsonString:NSDictionary){

    var abc: NSDictionary?

    // This is the action performed when clicked on the Connect button on the connectivity screen

    println("------------------Function connserv")

    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var IP: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("IP")!

    var port: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("Port")!

    println("IP in Connection : \(IP)")

    println("port in Connection : \(port)")

    prefs.synchronize()


    let localizedModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().localizedModel

    let model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model

    let devicesystemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion

    println("HTTP request jsonString : \(jsonString)")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://\(IP):\(port)/")!)
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    //var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://\(IP):\(port)/")!)
    //var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil


    var error: NSError?

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    // send the request
    println("HTTP request : \(request)")
    var e: NSError?

    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &e)

    debugPrintln(response)

    println("response-------------------------> : \(response)")
}
```

When the above function executed, server does not receive any thing and gives the following error:

```
HTTP request : <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7c8bb240> { URL: https://144.1.1.45:9299/ }
2015-04-07 11:16:59.661 MyApp[996:24843] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)nil
response-------------------------> : nil
2015-04-07 11:16:59.663 MyApp[996:24600] Unknown class UIAlert in Interface Builder file.
```

I want to return server response (variable response) to the calling function of the connserv function. Please help me to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Have you checked that your server is reachable from your machine? Try to ping or send a curl message to your server.

Comment: yes, the server is reachable

Comment: It seems like some problem with Server SSL. Check some documentation for kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL.

Comment: You seem to be trying to access an IP address, 144.1.1.45, about which nothing is known. And you are trying to access a port, 9299, which is not used for normal traffic. I have no idea what you are trying to do, but the server you are trying to talk to does not seem to exist.

Comment: Emrys57, I am re-explaing the scenario where I have an issue. I was able to connect to the server (IP: 144.1.1.45, Port: 9299), send a JSON request and receive the server response using asynchronous communication, but I was not able to return the server response to its calling function. Such thing happen because the execution of the connserv function returned before receiving the response from the server as per your clarification and suggestion on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414140/network-api-to-return-http-response-in-iphone.

Comment: @Emrys57- I am continuing may last comment further. I tried to connect the server synchronously so that I can return the server response to its calling function. But the new code gives me an error and doesn't send the request to the server. I hope you have a better idea now. Please help me.

Comment: As I am trying to establish the https connection, it seems that issue is related to certificate.